# Strange behaviour in angular template

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm doing angular app. And after dynamically including a template, the included html messes up. Here's how my app looks:

---

**index.html**

```
<div class="container">
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

HTML where we use dynamic include

---

**title.html**

```
<select class="system" ng-model="system" ng-options="system for system in select_system" ng-change="addCommands()"></select>
<br/>
<select class="commands" ng-show="commands_exist()"  ng-model="template" ng-options="command.name for command in select_commands">
</select>

<div ng-include="template.url" class="container">
</div>
```

And the included template:

---

**checkjob.html**

```
<h3>checkjob</h3>

<table>
  <tr>
      <td>
        <select ng-model="option">
          <option>-l</option>
          <option>-n</option>
          <option>-q</option>
          <option>-v</option>
        </select>
      </td>

      <td>
        <p>[-l policylevel]</p>
        <p>[-n nodeid]</p>
        <p>[-q qosid]</p>
        <p>[-r reservationid]</p>
        <p>[-v] [--flags=future]</p>
      </td>

      <td class="col-md-2">
        <input type="text" ng-model="param1">
        <label>jobID:</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="param2">
        <button>Enter</button>
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The thing is that in jsfiddle my html looks normal, but in my app it looks bad.
My app:
[image]

JSfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/y1hkmkse/

Comment: I'm using bootstrap css here only. And this should work without css at all, in my idea.

Comment: seems like you have a `position: absolute` , like here: http://jsfiddle.net/y1hkmkse/1/ , if so ,fix it like: http://jsfiddle.net/y1hkmkse/2/

Comment: As you can see in your fiddle, it does work without the CSS. If you're using only bootstrap then it's most likely due to it (you're using bootstrap wrong).

Comment: Thx Cherniv, that was dumb question =\. Sorry to bother.